# C++ thread termination with waiting window

Tags: c++, winapi

So, the code goes somehow like this:

```
MAIN(){
/*waiting window class declaration*/
    threadinfo* oThread=new threadinfo(); //An object that will help me know when to finish the thread
    QueueUserWorkItem((LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)waitingWindow, (void*)mThread, WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION);
    function_that_takes_time();
    oThread->setTerminated(); //set member terminated to bool true
/*continue with other things*/
}
```

and waitingWindow function that will run on that thread

```
MSG msg;
hwndWaiting=CreateWindow(...) // here the window is created
while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, null, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else
        {
            if(oThread->isTerminated()) // isTerminated returns bool true if terminated
            {
                delete oThread;
                ExitThread(0);
            }
        }
    }
ExitThread(0);
```

Is ExitThread a good way to remove the waiting window, and safely remove the thread? (at least I'm **100% sure** this way when to end it).

I'm asking this because this works nice in Windows XP, but will crash with "the application has stopped working" on Windows 7.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: ExitThread is wrong. Do you know that in your code it exits the calling thread which I don't think is your intention. But just don't call it at all. Ask your thread to terminate and wait until it does so.

Comment: When you say "ask your thread to terminate", I presume you mean I can still use the oThread and use a different function to end the thread? (like _endThread())? or return a value instead?

Comment: No. You send a message to the thread telling it that you wish for it to terminate. Then you wait until it can do so at a point of its convenience.

Comment: So you mean to place it in the while condition, and go out if it's "finished", and removing all the calls to ExitThread()? However, if I do that, it will crash when it ends for some reason (maybe the call to QueueUserWorkItem()) is wrong itself?

Comment: ExitThread is just wrong. Stop it. That exits the calling thread but it looks like you want another thread to stop. You can't just kill a thread. Well, you can but what if it's holding a lock? Signal it to terminate and wait. By wait I mean use a wait function like WaitForSingleObject or some equivalent.

Comment: I've applied this and it works perfect on both OS now. I have to say it's really strange that it did work in XP and not in W7 though. Thanks for the help. I'm wondering though, ExitThread() purpose is closing the parent thread?

Comment: `ExitThread()` is what you call when your thread function is finished and wishes to return an exit code to the main controlling thread. You call it within the thread and it acts by closing the calling thread. If you are writing C++ threading code though you typically just return the exit code from your thread function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to end threads in general, is to let them "gracefully" finish up by themselves. You could tell the thread to end by setting an event, for example:

```
HANDLE hevent_die = CreateEvent(...);  
HANDLE hthread_something = CreateThread(...); // or _beginthread()
...

DWORD WINAPI thread_func (LPVOID param)
{
  while(working && WaitForSingleObject(hevent_die, 0)!=WAIT_OBJECT_0)
  {
    ...
  }

  return 0;
}


while (msg.message != WM_QUIT)
{
   ...

   if(WaitForSingleObject(hthread_something, 0) == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
   {
     // do things if needed
   }
}

SetEvent(hevent_die);
WaitForSingleObject(hthread_something, INFINITE);

CloseHandle(hthread_something);
CloseHandle(hevent_die);
hthread_something = 0;
hevent_die = 0;
```

If you are using nested loops inside the thread function, they too will have to end if they receive the event.

Comment: This looks good as well. I will try to see about those Events and will comeback to report later.

Answer (score 3):

You should exit your loop and thread cleanly so that any destructors are called correctly. Don't use ExitThread(), just use a flag to indicate when to exit the loop and then just exit your waitingWindow function at the end.